# Jetpack navigation compose, bottom nav, make back button switch tabs?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-bottomnav, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm trying to use bottom navigation (ie, tabs) with Android Jetpack Compose and the [Navigation Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation) library. I have it set up with multiple back stacks, so that the state of each tab is preserved when you switch between them. However, if I change tabs by tapping one of them, the Android back button does *not* go back to the previous tab. Instead it navigates within that tab. How do I set it up to go *back* to previous tab?

Example scenario (I want to change behavior of last step).

1. I have two tabs, A and B.
2. Start in the A tab, on screen A1.
3. Push a new screen in that tab, called A2.
4. Tap the B tab to move to it, on its start screen B1.
5. Push a new screen in that tab, B2. So the tab stacks are now: A:[A1,A2], and B:[B1, B2]
6. Tap the A tab. I'm back in that stack, on screen A2. The state in that tab was preserved.
7. Press Android back button. It goes to A1. Instead I want it to go back to the B tab, screen B2.

```
MyAppBottomNavItem.all.forEach { item ->
    BottomNavigationItem(
        icon = { Icon(item.icon, contentDescription = null) },
        label = {
            Text(item.name, maxLines = 1, textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                 overflow = TextOverflow.Visible, softWrap = false,
                 fontSize = 10.sp)
        },
        selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == item.route } == true,
        alwaysShowLabel = true,
        onClick = {
            nav.navigate(item.route) {
                popUpTo(nav.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                    saveState = true
                }
                launchSingleTop = true
                restoreState = true
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: This is a confusing requirement. You have mimicked Instagram bottom ba navigation perfectly. In the 7th step, Instagram works exactly like your app currently does.

If you want B2 to be shown on the back press when would be A1 shown?

Comment: The app has a back or "up" button within the app, at the left side of the top bar. That would go to A1. If this behavior I'm seeing is standard within Android, maybe I need to push back on the people asking it to work differently.

Comment: Have the same issue. Loogin for solution in 2022